# AWS executes a userdata when the ec2 instance is created, but throws an error for double brackets and double dollars

Tags: linux, bash

i am experiencing a fundamental problem with double brakcets and double dollar signs in ec2 linux instances when the startup script is executed by AWS auto scaling group.

below is the error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

below is the code

```
#!/bin/bash

total_ram=`free -g | awk 'FNR > 1 && FNR < 3 {print $2}'`
# if it's an odd value add one
if [ $$((total_ram%2)) -ne 0 ]; then total_ram=$$((total_ram+1)) ; fi
# divide by two
#  half_ram=$((total_ram / 2))

sed "s,Xms.*,Xms$$((half_ram+0))g,g" -i /Users/rrapolu/ProjectDocs/shell/jvm.options
sed "s,Xmx.*,Xmx$$((half_ram+0))g,g" -i /Users/rrapolu/ProjectDocs/shell/jvm.options
```

Comment: Use 1 dollar sign `$` instead of 2

Comment: Thanks Oliv, yeah i tried with a single $ after i raised the case, it worked.Thanks once again for your quick response.